# Joomla frontend user removed from groups automatically on log in / log out

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-user-groups, bugs

I have this weird bug everytime I log into Joomla with a non-administrative user. Every time the user logs into the site, he is removed out of all Joomla user groups, except the Registered group. I also opened up the Joomla administrative console in a different browser, and assigned the user back to those groups, but every page visit (after the non-admin user is logged in) it removes him out of the group again. Logging out does the same. I'm at a loss after spending several hours on this, trying to figure out what is happening here.

The only thing that has changed to make this happen is upgrading the server to PHP 7.3.8 and Apache to 2.4. I'm doubtful as to whether that is the cause of the problem, but you never know.

Also, another piece of information, the user is only not removed from groups when he also is a part of the super user group. This makes me think that there is some condition that first checks for super users and then does some logic. I've disabled two plugins related to adding/removing from groups, thinking it was a bug with either, but I can still replicate the issue.

Furthermore, I've added in debug statements to the `JUserHelper::removeUserFromGroup` function, but those are not even called when the user is taken out of the group!

Comment: What exact version of Joomla are you running?  What extensions remain active (which ones didn't you disable?) Can you turn the debugging all the way up from the backend and review the long list of queries being executed? (I hate having to scan through them all, but it seems necessary here.)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The version that I am running is 3.9.1, although I can replicate this on my staging instance which runs the latest 3.9.12. Extensions enabled are too many to list down, so not sure what to do here. How to do I turn debugging up all the way?

Comment: https://www.pipeten.com/support/applications/joomla-debugging-error-logging/ or https://www.joomlashack.com/blog/joomla/how-to-turn-your-error-reporting-to-maximum/ or https://readybytes.in/blog/a-beginners-guide-to-start-debugging-joomla or https://docs.joomla.org/How_to_debug_your_code

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! I followed the steps like you said and I was able to find the query responsible for removing the user out of the group. Turns out, it was the JomClassifieds plugin which was responsible. It checked if the user had any memberships and removed it out from all groups (except the registered one) if it didn't.

Comment: Please take a moment to share your discovery as an answer to your own question.  Please be as clear and generous as you can about what you did to self-solve.  Good work.